# Autocomplate like facebook - list always appear

Tags: list, hide, blur, onblur

I download example of autocomplate search list

> The Problem is the list of people always appear even i
>   click outside of list area, i must delete the data from input field to disappear.
>
> What i want when i click any where this list hide or disappear when i
>   click or enter any data appear again inside input field .

About source code

- **index.php**
- **js.js (java)**
- **db.php (Database)**

---

**index code is :**

```
<body bgcolor="#F1f1f1">
<div id='val'>
  <div>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id ="test"  name="n" onblur="message()" onclick="showHint(this.value)"   onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" placeholder="Search here"   autocomplete="off"  autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" />
      <img src="Black_Search.png" class="search" width="20" height="20">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='val2'>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <div id='more'> <a href='#' class='search_profile'>see more result</a></div>
</div>
```

**java js.js Code is:**

```
function showHint(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  { 

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
  document.getElementById("val2").style.display = "none";

  return;
  }



if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("val2").style.display="block"; 
    }

  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","db.php?n="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**Database db.php code :**

```
if(@mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_GET['n']))){
$_dblocal='localhost';
$_dbrott='root';
$_dbpassword='';
$_dbname='search';
@mysql_connect($_dblocal,$_dbrott,$_dbpassword)  or die (mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db($_dbname) or die (mysql_error());
$sele="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE name LIKE '" .$_GET['n']. "%' ORDER BY id DESC  LIMIT 5";

$que=@mysql_query($sele);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($que)){

$id= $rows['id'];
$name= $rows['name'];
$images = $rows['image'];
$desc= $rows['desc'];

echo "<a href='profile.php?id=$id' class='search_profile' > 
<div class='comment'>
 <img src='images/$images' width='40' height='40' align='top' class='Square' >
<b>$name</b>
<div class='dec'>$desc</div> 


</div> </a>";

}

}else{
echo "Enter Name";  
}
```

Comment: before asking you should show some own effort in solving this problem. What have you tried?

Comment: i did,  i add this  function message() {
 document.getElementById("val2").style.display = "none"; 
     } in js.js  and in index.php i replace input with this line <input type="text" id ="test"  name="n" onblur="message()" onclick="showHint(this.value)"   onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" placeholder="Search here"   autocomplete="off"  autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" /> it work fine but i face new problem when i click any item in result list no action , when i disable function messege action work but list appear always again